# ActiveJDBC DBSpec - JUnit5 support

Tags: activejdbc, javalite

For a JavaEE project with working JUnit 5 tests I decided to give ActiveJDBC a try. Unfortunately I implemented all the tests with JUnit 5 before this decision so I have to update my tests for the usage with ActiveJDBC and was wondering why they won't get the test-db connection out of the database.properties file when extending the class with 'DBSpec' and just throw an DBException when using JUnit version 5 instead of version 4:

> org.javalite.activejdbc.DBException: Failed to retrieve metadata from DB, connection: 'default' is not available

**JUnit 5 - test**

```
import org.javalite.activejdbc.test.DBSpec;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
public class MyModelTest extends DBSpec {
  //Test will fail with DBException
  @Test
  public void one() {
    MyModel model = new MyModel();
    a(model).shouldBe("valid");
  }
}
```

**JUnit 5 - dependencies**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

---

When i switch to JUnit 4, everything works as expected

**JUnit 4 - test**

```
import org.javalite.activejdbc.test.DBSpec;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MyModelTest extends DBSpec {
  //Test will pass
  @Test
  public void one() {
    MyModel model= new MyModel();
    a(model).shouldBe("valid");
  }
}
```

**JUnit 4 - dependencies**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

---

It won't be that much of a deal to just 'rewrite' my tests for JUnit4 but are there any plans to support JUnit5 in the near future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, JUnit5 is not supported yet. We filed a new issue: https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/issues/784 to add support for it. Please, track it to see when the next snapshot will be available.

Comment: That issue has bee resolved for some time, you might want to try a new snapshot